# Post Overwintering chilli

Tags: chili

Hi my two chillis had an ok summer.. they came in a bit late and had some light and water through winter 
Basically they’ve lost leaves and appear to have some growth nodes at the base... shall I save the plants some energy and prune trunk back by 50% making them less leggy?
They west facing in north west uk where we are experiencing unusually good weather..[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would cut it in the lower half. As you say, it needs to focus the energy to get back leaves. Please keep in mind that the most important part of your plant is the one in the soil. You still got the root system for a bigger plant and should not be afraid to cut it down.

Even though I grow mostly inside, I regularly cut branches down to help them grow out new branches and get more fruits. You will also get a more bushy plant that way. Remember that it's in the branch junctions most fruits will grow.